# Changing background color if a list-item onClick and reset other items

Tags: javascript, css

```js
for (const doc of docs) {
    // create a `div` element
    const div = document.createElement("li");
    div.classList.add("list-group-item");
    div.style.border = "none";

    // add a text node to it
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc.name));

    // add event listeners to change its background
    div.addEventListener("mouseover", e => { div.style.background = "#e9ecef"; });
    if (div.style.backgroundColor !== "#e9ecef") {
        div.addEventListener("mouseout", e => { div.style.background = "white"; });
    }
    // add a `click` listener
    div.addEventListener("click", e => {
        updateInput(doc);

        var listGroup = document.getElementById("list-group-row").getElementsByTagName('li');
    });

    // add the new div to the container
    container.appendChild(div);
}
```

This is a loop that I add list-items into my container.
The `addEventListener` for `mouseover` and `mouseout` gives an effect for changing background color when we hover and change back to white when hovered out.

My problem is in the `addEventListener` `click` part. 
I tried to change the `.style.backgroundColor` of `div`, but obviously this changes the color of other list-items to since it's inside a for-loop.

What is the best way to make individual list-item to change backgroundColor onClick and change back when other item is clicked?

I also want to keep the `mouseover` and `mouseout` effect.

**FULL CODE:**

```
    VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData)
    // the callback on the next line returns a promise, which the JavaScript engine will follow, so you don't need to nest the next `then`
        .then((dataService) => dataService.getDocuments('MyCollection2'))
        .then((docs) => {
            // keep a reference to the element instead of searching for it in each loop.
            const container = document.getElementById('items');

            // this loop will remove any existing children
            while (container.firstChild !== null) {
                container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
            }

            // `for...of` is a simpler way to iterate over a collection
            for (const doc of docs) {
                // create a `div` element
                const div = document.createElement("li");
                div.classList.add("list-group-item");
                div.style.border = "none";

                // add a text node to it
                div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc.name));

                // add event listeners to change its background
                div.addEventListener("mouseover", e => { div.style.background = "#e9ecef"; });
                div.addEventListener("mouseout", e => { div.style.background = "white"; });

                // add a `click` listener
                //get all the elements with calss list-group-item
                [...document.querySelectorAll('.list-group-item')].forEach(function(item) {
                    // iterate and add event lstener to each of them
                    item.addEventListener('click', function(elem) {
                        // check if any element have a class active
                        // if so then remove the class from it
                        let getElemWithClass = document.querySelector('.clicked');
                        if (getElemWithClass !== null) {
                            getElemWithClass.classList.remove('clicked');
                            getElemWithClass.classList.add('unClicked')
                        }
                        //add the active class to the element from which click event triggered
                        item.classList.add('clicked')

                    })
                })


                // add the new div to the container
                container.appendChild(div);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Always add ***all*** of the relevant code so that we can have an executable example to work from and provide you with an executable answer. Please edit the question to include the ***relevant*** HTML and CSS.

Comment: Also (just curious), why does your comment and variable name indicate you are making a `div`, when in fact, you are making an `li`?

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to attach the event inside the loop. Create a new function to attach the event but call this function only when the loop have finished it's execution depends on the availability of the element with class `list-group-item`

```js
//get all the elements with calss list-group-item
[...document.querySelectorAll('.list-group-item')].forEach(function(item) {
  // iterate and add event lstener to each of them
  item.addEventListener('click', function(elem) {
    // check if any element have a class active
    // if so then remove the class from it
    let getElemWithClass = document.querySelector('.active');
    if (getElemWithClass !== null) {
      getElemWithClass.classList.remove('active');
    }
    //add the active class to the element from which click event triggered
    item.classList.add('active')

  })
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<li class="list-group-item"> 1 </li>
<li class="list-group-item"> 2 </li>
<li class="list-group-item"> 3 </li>
<li class="list-group-item"> 4 </li>
```

Comment: Works great. One small problem remaining is that the `mouseout` eventlistener keeps the item' background color white even though it's clicked. I added my code to edit. Thanks.